# mysql alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

i am trying to sort mysql data with alphabeticaly like

A | B | C | D

when i click on B  this query runs

> select name from user order by 'b'

but result showing all records starting with a or c or d i want to show records only starting with b

thanks for help

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> i want to show records only starting with b

```
select name from user where name LIKE 'b%';
```

> i am trying to sort MySQL data alphabeticaly

```
select name from user ORDER BY name;
```

> i am trying to sort MySQL data in reverse alphabetic order

```
select name from user ORDER BY name desc;
```

Answer (score 7):

> but result showing all records
>   starting with a or c or d i want to
>   show records only starting with b

You should use `WHERE` in that case:

```
select name from user where name = 'b' order by name
```

If you want to allow regex, you can use the [`LIKE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) operator there too if you want. Example:

```
select name from user where name like 'b%' order by name
```

That will select records starting with `b`. Following query on the other hand will select all rows where `b` is found anywhere in the column:

```
select name from user where name like '%b%' order by name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE name like 'b%' ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the rows that are returned by a query, you need to use a `WHERE` clause, rather than an `ORDER BY` clause. Try

```
select name from user where name like 'b%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to user where clause while ordering the data alphabetically.
here is my code

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY field_name
```

that's it.
It return the data in alphabetical order ie; From A to Z.
:)

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard Characters are used with like clause to sort records.

If we want to search a string which is starts with B then code is like the following:

```
select * from tablename where colname like 'B%' order by columnname ;
```

If we want to search a string which is ends with B then code is like the following:

```
select * from tablename where colname like '%B' order by columnname ;
```

If we want to search a string which is contains B then code is like the following:

```
select * from tablename where colname like '%B%' order by columnname ;
```

If we want to search a string in which second character is B then code is like the following:

```
select * from tablename where colname like '_B%' order by columnname ;
```

If we want to search a string in which third character is B then code is like the following:

```
select * from tablename where colname like '__B%' order by columnname ;
```

*Note : one underscore for one character.*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge, but after little research I came up with this and it gave me what I wanted, and I was able to overcome that path.

```sql
SELECT * from TABLE ORDER BY name
```

Comment: How does this Answer add something new?

Answer (score 0):

I  try to sort data with query it working  fine for me please try this:

```
select name from user order by name asc
```

Also try below query for search record by alphabetically

```
SELECT name  FROM `user` WHERE `name` LIKE 'b%'
```

Comment: This answer is the same as all the other answers. Why are you posting it?

Comment: @LuFFy Why did you edit this post? The first part isn't an answer to the question (and has already been supplied in the accepted answer) and the second part is just copying every other answer.

Comment: I just formatted the answer.. you can see the difference by clicking on `edited` link.

Comment: @LuFFy Sorry for the late reply. (You forgot to "ping" me ;) )  What I meant to say was that this answer should have been deleted. Are you aware that editing forces the question out of the LQP review queue, cancelling the current votes and causing it to remain undeleted? From the tooltip *"__Edit__ if you can fix all the problems with this answer"*, it can be seen that you should only choose `Edit` if the answer needs to remain. Answers that are copies of other answers, without any additional, ***useful*** information, are at worst plagiarism and at best "noise". They should be deleted.

Comment: @LuFFy Choosing `Edit` should be reserved for when you are ***absolutely sure*** that your edit either converts a delete-worthy answer into one that is not (for example, adding in the appropriate info for a link-only answer), or improves a genuine low quality answer so that is not low quality anymore (for example, fixing the grammar/spelling/punctuation/capitalisations/formatting in a difficult to understand, possibly no-code, answer). You must also have checked to see if the answer actually attempts to answer the question **and** is not a copy of existing answers…

Comment: …If you just wish to improve the formatting, typos, and minor spelling/grammar/punctuation errors, bookmark the review and then choose `Looks OK`, `Recommend Deletion` or `Skip`, as appropriate. *After* the review has finished, edit the answer if it hasn't been deleted. (Note that it is alright to use `Looks OK` if you do not wish to analyse all the other answers.)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL solution:

```
select Name from Employee order by Name ;
```

Order by will order the names from a to z.