# How to use group by and order by

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I group a photo gallery and sort them alphabetically in ascending order?
my code:

```
$getid = $_SESSION['idSession'];

$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "
SELECT name_gallery
     , folder
     , img
     , id_client 
  FROM alboom 
 WHERE id_adm = '$getid' 
 GROUP 
    BY id_client 
 ORDER 
    BY name_gallery ASC
");
```

my table struct
[table struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJvnA.jpg)

my output = `test gallery01, test gallery02, test gallery03, test gallery04, test gallery05`;

How should I do for my code to sort images in alphabetical order?

Comment: Can you add the table structure and expected output?

Comment: try to look at this topic [mysql result order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968135/mysql-alphabetical-order)

Comment: what we need to know is what results are you getting now and what the intended results are to be? we don't know how you're echoing those neither. Your question is still unclear.

Comment: @DarshanMehta i edit my Ask question with `img` table struct and output

Comment: You have no aggregating functions, and therefore no requirement for a `group by` clause. Maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge on mysql but it's almost similar to Oracle

SELECT name_gallery
     , folder
     , img
     , id_client 
  FROM alboom 
 WHERE id_adm = '$getid' 
 GROUP 
    BY name_gallery
     , folder
     , img
     , id_client 
 ORDER 
    BY name_gallery 
");

ASC is not required to sort in ascending.